# Performance issue for webserver

Tags: asp.net, performance, dotnetnuke

We have asp.net sites based on dotnetnuke architecture and we are having two load balancing server with 2 gigs and with 24GB Ram. and SQL Server is with 48GB Ram. But still we are having some problem with sites and its heating 100% cpu usage.

We have multiple instance of this site for each client wise one virtual directory for each client and domain. I need to find out what process is causing that problem.

Its not all time at 100% but during some time like for 2 minutes its bags to 100% cpu usage i need to find out that why its causing we have lots of pages in our site. I need to find out whats going on with application.

We have tried RedGate Profile for code issues and we have resolved that issue but still there was some part of application that is causing problem and we need to find out that.

Is there any tool of anything that is there from which we can find out webserver load and reason for cause of the going for 100%.

We have also profiled our SQL Server and its running normal there is only problem with web server only.

Any tip or help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help or tip.

Comment: I started to re-write this to make it more obvious that it's a programming question... And realized then that it's not. If you want to track down problems with an ASP.NET app, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052633/w3wp-exe-using-100-cpu-where-to-start); if you want to identify the app you're hosting that's hiking the CPU load, [read this](http://serverfault.com/questions/107732/when-is-sustained-100-cpu-utilization-not-a-worry).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get unnecessarily kicked to SF but until you do.

I would use [dynaTrace](https://web.archive.org/web/20160722141623/http://www.dynatrace.com:80/en/). However you may be looking for a quicker/free'er solution.

I would check the IIS logs and see what is taking so long to serve.  You might look into [log parser](http://www.symantec.com/connect/de/articles/forensic-log-parsing-microsofts-logparser).

I would also use WinDbg after pulling out a hang dump using adplus following what [Tess tells you to do](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031100114/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-lab-1-hang.aspx).

Have Fun!